# Создания графа из изображения карты помещения

Tags: android, алгоритм, карты, графы, поиск-пути

Доброго времени суток!

В качестве курсовой работы взял проект по созданию android-приложения навигатор по корпусу учебного заведения. Имеются изображения с планом каждого этажа. Подскажите, каким способом можно составить из изображения плана здания граф для поиска путей?  Вот пример  плана этажа:[image: Пример плана этажа]

У меня была идея нарисовать поверх изображения сетку, и составить матрицу, в которой:

- 0 - дорога
- 1 - аудитория
- 2 - стена

Есть ли ещё какие-то способы сделать это?

Comment: Можно сеткой, а можно и графом (из вершин и ребер)

Comment: Опишите результат, который вы хотите увидеть. Почти уверен, что тэги для вопроса подобраны неверно, нет смысла на андроиде проводить конвертацию планов в какие-то модельки для приложения. Один раз сделали на компе, положили результат в приложение

Comment: А вообще в масштабах конкретной задачи кажется лучшим решением размечать все вручную. Даже на пару десятков корпусов это займет куда меньше времени, чем разработка какого-то универсального автоматизированного решения. Разные виды планов, сращивание планов между этажами и пр. все арвно требует того или иного уровня ручной разметки

Answer (score 3):

Сначала о вашем предложении метить на дороги, стены и аудитории. Возникает простой вопрос: а зачем? зачем вам знать о местоположениях стен, если нужно построить маршрут по известным дорогам? То есть стены запоминать смысла нет. И аудитории как-то отдельно выделять тоже. Вам нужен один граф, вершины которого находятся у дверей в аудитории, на поворотах, на лестницах, и некое отношение "номер аудитории -> "соответствующая ей вершина в графе". То есть вершины, относящиеся к аудиториям, не слишком-то нуждаются в отдельной обработке, надо просто отдельно их запомнить.

Должно быть как-то так:[image: Пример графа путей на плане]

Создаете отдельное приложение(как по мне куда удобнее все же на десктопе), в котором вы будете создавать свои карты. Допустим, вы работаете только с картами корпусов, без связи корпусов друг с другом. Тогда основной модельный элемент - корпус. Корпус состоит из набора планов(уровней), списка аудиторий и графа. Вершины графа имеет: уникальный id, координаты x,y и уровень.
Открыв в вашем редакторе такой модельный элемент вы можете переключаться между уровнями, ставить новые вершины и рисовать ребра между ними. Не забываем про веса ребер, соответствующие расстоянию между точками в реальном мире для адекватного поиска короткого пути. Ну и список аудиторий, к которым можно привязать одну или несколько точек(на вашем плане столовой можно привязать 2 точки)
После этих операций у вас есть возможность найдя через поиск номер аудитории отобразить юзеру место, в котором она расположена(от аудитории ищем точку графа, у которой есть нужные нам уровень и координаты). Поиск пути от точки, указанной юзером как его местоположение, до искомой аудитории - элементарный поиск пути во взвешенном графе.

Есть ряд технических омментов. Например, отображать на телефонах сами планы больно. Плотность пикселей на телефонах/планшетах скачет разительно, и для адекватного отображения надо резать планы на куски. Глупо рисовать весь этаж, если в экран влезает только 10% от него, на некоторых телефонах для этого даже памяти может не хватить. А если вы допускаете зум, то делать кучу картинок разной плотности и качества. Например, на самом большом отдалении вы показываете одну картинку 500 на 500, вмещающую весь план. При приближении берете большего качества план размером 1000 на 1000 и дробите на 4 части, отрисовывая только те, которые попали в кадр, приближая еще больше берете план в качестве 2к на 2к порезанный на 16 частей и т.д и т.п. Муторное дело и довольно дорогое в плане постоянной памяти

Можно вместо отрисовки картинок отрисовывать полигонами с помощью OpenGL. Это избавит вас от кучи разных картинок из-за разных плотностей пикселей экранов, сильно упростит жизнь  с зумом. Но это заметно труднее реализовывать и нужно в вашем редакторе карт создавать инструментарий для создания полигонов и их триангуляции, установки каких-то меток... На диплом потянуть может уже проект, а если сильно захотеть, то и на кандидатскую

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю насчет матриц, хотелось бы посмотреть, но графом будет вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если представить это в виде классического графа, то получится вот такая картина (я взял только верхнюю часть плана с выходами L и G, остальные аналогично)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь зеленые стрелочки (двунаправленные) говорят о том, что вдоль данного ребра можно двигаться в обоих направлениях, красные - однонаправленные ребра.

Добавил еще красный крест - как вариант, если выход недоступен и требуется продолжить поиск.

Движение, соответственно, осуществляется снизу-вверх. В самом верху добавлена мнимая вершина (корень) для общности, поиск обрывается на узлах с буквами