# Разработка мобильного приложения

Tags: java, android, python, парсер

Появилась идея для создания приложения - ассистента для студентов своего ВУЗ'а. Однако уже на начальном этапе столкнулся с рядом проблем и вопросов.

**1)** Приложение должно выводить расписание в соответствии с группой студента, естественно есть необходимость брать расписание с сайта ВУЗ'а, расписание на сайте в excel файле. С помощью чего можно брать excel файл с расписанием.

***Страница с расписанием*** - [клик](https://www.mirea.ru/education/schedule-main/schedule/)

По данной странице идут подряд названия институтов, чтобы увидеть excel файлы необходимо нажать на свой институт, дальше появятся курсы и выбираешь свой курс и начинается скачивание файла. Можно ли с помощью Python брать нужное расписание? То есть user в приложении указывает свой институт, свой курс и группу, а приложение ему в красивом виде загружает его расписание. Можно ли такой функционал реализовать с помощью Python/Java?

2) В приложении предполагается интерактивная навигация по аудиториям. И вот собственно сам вопрос, как можно реализовать интерактивную схему университета, на примере схем торговых центров ? (см. скриншот ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S** Только интерактивная будет иметь вид сверху.

Посоветуйте какими готовыми решениями можно воспользоваться или как попроще можно сделать ту или иную часть приложения. Может если есть ресурсы схожие с тематикой поделитесь ими. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее - на stackOverflow есть правило: один вопрос - один вопрос. В будущем если у вас два разных вопрос, хоть и связанных одним приложением, создавайте два вопроса. Так будет проще тем, кто будет искать ответ на такой же вопрос в будущем

Про карту университета совсем [недавно был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049179/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/1049292#1049292). Уж не из одного ли вы университета? =)

Парсить эксель можно с помощью [POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Определить нужный файл для скачивания будет чуть сложнее, чем вы думаете. Большая часть адреса легко читается по параметрам(институт, курс, семестр), но там используется рандомный ключ.

> https://www.mirea.ru/upload/medialibrary/**7b1**/IK_1k_19_20_vesna-*1*.xlsx

Эти три символа специально добавили, чтобы просто так никто не парсил сайт и не качал все доступные файлы. Я бы рассмотрел другие варианты, например сделать свой сервер и руками/скриптом перекидывать на него расписания, чтобы приложение их брало уже оттуда. Ну или вообще связаться с отедлом информатизации или его аналогом в вашем вузе и попробовать договориться о сотрудничестве, чтобы у вас был какой-то свой инструмент для получения расписаний. Ради благой цели вам вполне могут пойти на встречу, особенно если кто-то из преподавателей за вас "впишется".

Если эти варианты не варианты - можно парсить страницу целиком и вытаскивать из нее нужные ссылки на файлы. Это не шибко сложно, но муторно. Делать это внутри приложения точно не хочется, я бы все же сделал скрипт, который будет вытаскивать со страницы ссылки и загружать расписание на ваш сервер. А в идеале еще и преобразовывало его в бд, например, чтобы не парсить эксель на устройствах. Раз в полгода его запускать руками терпимо, на ранних этапах.

Вообще за свой сервер говорят еще несколько вещей. Представьте что сайт незначителньо меняется. Тогда ваша программа переставет работать у пользователей до тех пор, пока вы не выпустите обновление и не на устройство пользователя это обновление не прилетит. Тоже самое произойдет если структура документа изменится. Так что подумайте над свои сервером и превращением таблиц экселя в таблицы бд

Comment: а как парсить сайт полностью? Чтобы получать существующие на нём ссылки на файлы

Comment: Сайт - это текст. Вам нужно этот текст получить, что сделать просто: Url("ссылка").openStream() и читаете поток данных, преобразуете в строку и ищете в тексте нужные вам вещи. В данному случае даже регулярками можно поискать, хотя вообще html парсить регулярками нельзя

Comment: на этой странице ищете тэг <a class="xls">, его содержимое - ссылка на один из нужных вам файлов

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Очень помогли